# SDS drill vs normal drill when drilling through external wall into joists behind

Tags: drill

When drilling into the ceiling void from outside, does an SDS drill with SDS wood arbor bit make drilling through the thick joists easier? It certainly did make drilling the brick wall much easier than my expansive DeWalt cordless.

I remember how difficult they were to drill with my small muscles and arbor drill bit when install a large network of down lighters.

Comment: I believe a sharp bit would be better or should I say the proper type of bit. Hammering a wood bit may actually slow the cutting process as the edge is pulled out of the wood. My guess you have generic bits the relief is much shallower so they take more force where a wood bit almost pulls itself in , that would be a disaster when used on metal. So look at the type of bits you are using first.

Comment: So could you please give me an example of a bit u would use then èother sds or  hex.  I am truely clueless so any help would be appreciated

Comment: If in need a large deep  hole I use a forester bit kind of like an auger with a screw tip, another type is spade bits again with a screw looking tip, last is wood only wood bits these won’t work on metal unless brass maybe aluminum they all come in standard shank round taper and even hex my favorite spade bit set is a Bosch hex with a screw tip, these can be used in a drill or a impact driver, my taper bits take a special hand crank and I have bored 1-1/2 holes with this tool but my arms were sore but it works hit a nail or cement and it takes time to fix the bit with a file and or stone